# ssas 2005 calculated member issue

Tags: ssas

I am using SSAS 2005. I have a measure group Sales (measure: sold value, units). Sales measure group is modelled to have key receipt id, line no. So receipt id will have duplicates.).

And another measure group Sales 1(single measure: Transactions): which is **count distinct** receipt id of sales measure group.

I have a calculated member ATV in cube - calculation: which is defined as: [Measures].[sold value] / [Measures].[Transactions]

Deployed and in browser add ATV to data. It reports error:

The member '[Transactions]' was not found in the cube when the string, [Measures].[Transactions], was parsed.

But I can run following query no problem in SSMS.

```
    select 
    [Measures].[Transactions] on columns
    from cube
```

And this works as well:

```
    with member [atv] as (
        [Measures].[Sold value]/[Measures].[Transactions]
    )       
    select 
    [atv] on columns
    from rmis
```

But this won't work and got exact same error message as in BIDS.

```
    select 
    [Measures].[ATV] on columns
    from rmis
```

Any idea why I got the error in BIDS?

Comment: Please post the exact definition of the `ATV` measure (switch the calculation to script mode using the appropriate toolbar button if you are not using the script view mode already). I suspect there is an error - maybe just a typo in the calculation expression.

Comment: @FrankPI you are absolutely right, it's a typo. Thanks a lot.